# DTF Orchestration instance struck in "Pending" Status

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, dtf

We are using Durable task framework https://github.com/Azure/durabletask for long running processes but facing issues with orchestration execution, there are some instances of orchestration which are available in Azure.Storage.Table.InstanceHistory00Hub but with Orchestration.Status = "Pending" and even after weeks they are not being processed.

I found those instance's messages in Dead-letter queue of /orchestrator , with reason "MaxDeliverCountExceeded"

[image]I think this might be because of input size, but we are using DTF implementation in which if input size increases the service bus limit it store's the input in blob and we have many such instances which successfully processed with input from blob, but these instances have nothing corresponding in blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a message from Azure Service Bus Queue is received more than the Max Delivery Count times from the Queue, the message will be dead-lettered with "MaxDeliverCountExceeded" as reason. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#exceeding-maxdeliverycount) for the official documentation.

Comment: I'm actually want to figure out why message of size in a specific range is not being processed by dtf, though the smaller and larger size payloads are being successfully processed.